# Как выполнить такую фильтрацию

Tags: python, django

Есть объекты товаров, собранные в кверисете `qs`. У каждого такого объекта есть несколько складов. В запросе я обращаюсь к сету складов через имя `in_stocks`. Мне нужно отфильтровать товары по минимальному суммарному количеству на складах. Например, чтобы на всех складах в сумме было не менее 100 таких товаров. Я делаю это так:

```py
qs = qs.annotate(all_qty=Sum('in_stocks__count')).filter(all_qty__gte=100)
```

Кроме количества, в модели товара на складе хранится еще информация о цене (price). Как мне использовать в рассчете суммарного количества только те склады, в которых `price` соответствует определенному условию?

Например отфильтровать товары с суммарным количеством на складах не менее 1000 с ценой на складе не более 5000.

Comment: ты гуглил фильтрацию django? нет? а чо сюда пришел?

Comment: @ДанилПерелыгин а ответ-то ты знаешь или нет?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django.db.models import Q, Sum

max_price = Q(in_stocks__price__lte=5000)
qs = qs.annotate(all_qty=Sum(
    'in_stocks__count', 
    filter=max_price)).filter(all_qty__gte=100)
```